# Routes executing twice in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning about angular js to develop better my apps in the front end, So I am trying do share the same data between controllers using $rootScope, but always I push something in variable inside $rootScope, the console show for me twice console log in the controllers, it looks like to each route execute twice, Anyone help me ?

The link with the code - http://pastebin.com/eNXFVv8h

Comment: Make sure you don't have ngController in HTML template.

Comment: In the partials i put the controller, but in the index has a ng-view but does not controller, is it a problem ?

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a problem. You don't have to declare `ng-controller` in partial templates, route configuration already has controller to be instantiated. Remove the one from template.

Comment: The partials

http://pastebin.com/3as8Db21